# Assembly: Organizing long segments of varied data

Tags: assembly, fasm

I am programming a game in assembly and I am wondering if there is a way to mix variable lengths on one line, in the way that you can define many variables of the same length in one line. Here's an example:

```
.Sprites:
    db $0f,120,39,$D506E3
```

This example fails on the last number in that list since it is not one byte. But this:

```
.Sprites:
    dl $0f,120,39,$D506E3
```

compiles and inserts empty space between the variables.
The reason I want to be able to vary the size is because this will be a table with many sprites, and each one has the same format, so it would be better to leave each one's data on one line than to use two lines that could be confused:

```
.Sprites:
    ?? $0f,120,39,$D506E3
    ?? $0b,110,39,$D5001C
    ?? $01,120,36,$D509A1
```

Comment: (1) What assembler are you using?  (2) Would you want `$D506E3` to assemble like the three bytes `d5 06 e3`, or 24-bit little-endian `e3 06 d5`, or 32-bit little-endian`00d506e3 = e3 06 d5 00`, or what?

Comment: I think most programs would have this data auto-generated by some other script which can then write out individual bytes for `db`.  Some assemblers like nasm also have `incbin` where you can import an external binary file without going to the trouble of converting it to `db` directives.

Comment: @NateEldredge 1.fasmg for the ti-84 pce. 2.I am actually using a memory label. It is a pointer to the sprite's pixel data. I want it to be in whatever format labels usually are in

Comment: Probably best to use 2 lines per record, so one can be `db` and the 2nd can be `dl`.  Or if your assembler has support for some kind of `struct` syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by making a macro in [fasmg](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=fasmg).

```
macro sprite? color*,x*,y*,spriteID*
    db color
    dw x
    db y
    dd spriteID
end macro
```

Comment: You could avoids a misaligned `dw` by re-ordering your struct into `x, y, color` order, for example.  Although since the whole thing is 8 bytes total, if the first one is 8 (or even 4) bytes aligned, no `dw` will cross a 4-byte boundary so on x86 CPUs with at least a 32-bit bus there probably wouldn't be any penalty for accessing at 2-byte object at an odd address within a 4-byte dword.  (IDK about really early x86 CPUs with caches, but modern x86 have no penalty for misaligned load/store within 32-byte chunks, or even within a 64-byte cache line.)  Still, it's a bit unusual to misalign data